# Json parse not getting the value inside the 2nd curly braces

Tags: json, excel, vba, ms-access

I am using ACCESS VBA to parse Json.

It is getting the value that are in the 1st curly braces.

But anything within the 2nd curly gives an error

> Wrong number of arguments of invalid property assignment

JSON:

```
[
  {
   "Number": 1,
   "Name": "John Doe",
   "DateOfB": "2018-05-05",
   "Place": {
           "Pl": 4,
           "Name": "England"
   }
  }
]
```

I am able to get the values for `Number`, `Name` and `DateofB`.

But I'm unable to get the value for `Place` for that I am getting the error.

I am using the widly available `clsJsonParser` module in my VBA application.

Comment: `Power Query` has a built-in JSON parser, which will separate out all the fields.

Answer (score 2):

Following the sample in the `clsJsonParser` this is what works for you:

```
Public Sub TestJSON()
    Dim JP As JSONParser
    Set JP = New JSONParser

    JP.Filename = "c:\myJson.txt"

    Dim varData As Variant
    Set varData = JP.Parse

    Debug.Print varData(1)("Number")
    Debug.Print varData(1)("Name")
    Debug.Print varData(1)("DateOfB")

    'You have to explicitely use a Dictionary type here to store the place.
    Dim placeDictionary As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set placeDictionary = varData(1)("Place")

    'Output all keys and items of the place dictionary:
    Dim index As Long
    For index = 0 To placeDictionary.Count - 1
        Debug.Print placeDictionary.Keys(index), placeDictionary.Items(index)
    Next index

    'Access place dictionary items by name:
    Debug.Print placeDictionary("Pl")
    Debug.Print placeDictionary("Name")
End Sub
```

You have to reference the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` to introduce the type `Scripting.Dictionary`.

Comment: What is the library reference needed to dim it? I am unable to Dim it, giving "User defined type not defined"
Dim JP As JSONParser

Comment: It `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`.

Comment: I have added the MS Scripting Runtime, But JSONParser is not an option in the drop down.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood. I wonder, because you wrote you already use that mentioned library `clsJsonParser`. I just downloaded `clsJSONParser.zip` from `http://www.christiaanheidema.nl/?Downloads`, extracted it and imported the class. Then I had to paste 2 or 3 procedures from that site (`http://www.christiaanheidema.nl/?General_functions`) to be able to compile. Didn't you do that?

Comment: I have downloaded the zip and did the import, but not the 2nd part. What is it about

Comment: After importing the file, try to compile your code. For me it didn't compile because 2 or 3 procedures were missing. You can find them on the mentioned site and paste them to a module.

Comment: This seems like a entire re-design of my code. my clsJsonParser from another site. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BzRSeswr8T9kcUxWWXY0N1l0Mlk

Answer (score 0):

Code Below Worked:

```
For Each Appt In JSON
        rs.AddNew
        rs!Appt_ID = Appt("Number")
        rs!ClientFullName = Appt("Name")
        rs!Appt_Date = Appt("DateOfB")
        rs!TC_Center = Appt("Place")("Pl")
rs.Update
```

Next